# why my ODataACtionParameters are null for POST request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, odata

Im new to .net development. Im trying to post a request to an webservice.

### Webservice implementaion

> ```
> [HttpPost]
>     public async Task<ICollection<BoConsolidatedData>> GetTesDatas(ODataActionParameters actionParameters)
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             var reqId = (int)actionParameters["ReqId"];
> ```

I use Chrome Advance REST client,where I set content type to application/json

I sent parameter in the body as JSOn

> {"ReqId":9481}

When I debug the service my **actionparameters** are always null. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Have you registered this function? Code should probably look something like this:

```
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

builder.Function("GetTesDatas")
    .ReturnsCollection<BoConsolidatedData>()
    .Parameter<int>("ReqId")
    .Required();
```

You can do this using the same modelbuilder you use to register your other OData resources.

Comment: Thanks.All functions are registered n the webAPI config.Other functions are working. Only this operation is not working.My request is hitting the endpoint.Why do I get 'actionParameters' is null?  I suspect my POST request is wrong?

Comment: I found the cause, I passed a DateTime parameter too which I haven't added in my above sample code snippet, that contained wrong format. SO json translation was wrong

Answer (score 1):

This could also happen if you mess up your parameters a bit. For example, if you have a nullable `Guid?` parameter in WebApiConfig but the client passes  in an `""` empty string, this will cause the parameters to be null.

Comment: What caused the error for me was that I was passing an int as a parameter, when it was expecting a string. Thank you!